# calculating pi using the monte carlo method java - calculation not working

Tags: java

I have to use the monte carlo method to calculate pi. Need to get xy coordinates between (-1,1). However everytime I run the program it gives me an answer of 0. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can anyone help?

```
package montecarlo;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.util.Random;

public class MonteCarlo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter total number of dart throws");

        int nThrows = keyboard.nextInt();

        double PI= calculatePi(nThrows);

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("PiEstimate.txt");

        ps.printf("PI estimate = %.4f", PI);

    }

    public static boolean insideCircle (double x, double y)
    {
        double range = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));

        return (range < 1.0);
    }

    public static double calculatePi(int nThrows) 
    {

        int dartsInCircle = 0;
        double piEstimate;
        Random rGenerator = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i < nThrows; i++) {
          double x = rGenerator.nextDouble()*Math.pow(-1, rGenerator.nextInt());
          double y = rGenerator.nextDouble()*Math.pow(-1, rGenerator.nextInt());
          if (insideCircle(x,y))
          dartsInCircle++;
    } piEstimate=(4.0*(dartsInCircle/nThrows));
    return piEstimate;

} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing an `int` by an `int` here: `(dartsInCircle/nThrows)`.

Since `dartsInCircle` will always be less than `nThrows`, the integer division will always return `0`. You will need to cast either one of the operands to double.

EDIT: If you use a good enough IDE (like IntelliJ), it should prompt you with a "loss of precision" warning or similar.